# Converter tipo Cell para String no Apache POI

Tags: java, string, apache-poi, planilha

De que forma posso converter um tipo `Cell` para `String` ?

```
String datateste = row.getCell(5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você [precisa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30125586/2387977) de um `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter` para isto. Exemplo:

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(5);
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
String datateste = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
```